# Magnification produced by combination of lenses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

In combination of thin lenses in contact, why is the total magnification(m) equal to the product of magnification of individual lenses(m1,m2,m3...)
That is, why m=m1m2m3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let lens $L_1$ have object place at $u$ and form an image at $x_1$. Now, let another lens $L_2$ have object placed at $x_1$ and form an image at $x_2$ and so on. The last lens will have object distance as $x_{n-1}$ and form an image $v$.

Observe that the magnification of each lens $L_i$is given by:
$$m_1=-\frac {x_1}u, m_n=-\frac v{x_{n-1}}$$
$$m_i=-\frac {x_i}{x_{i-1}}$$

The final magnification of the combination of the lenses is $m=-\frac vu$. Observe what happens when we multiply the magnification of all lenses.
$$m_1\times m_2\times m_3\cdots \times m_n=-\frac {x_1}{u}\times-\frac {x_2}{x_1}\times-\frac {x_3}{x_2}\cdots \times-\frac {v}{x_{n-1}}=-\frac vu$$